# Add a character on a list if a situation presents

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, split

enter code hereI have this script:

```
accounts = open("accounts.txt").readlines()

y = [x.strip().split(":") for x in accounts]

for position, account in enumerate(y):
    try:
        print ("Trying with: %s:%s @%d" % (account[0], account[1], position))
    except:
        pass
```

it opens a file (accounts.txt) that is structured like this:

```
email1@email.com:test1
email2@email.com:test2
email3@email.comtest3
email4@email.comtest4
```

Since I want to split the email and the password, I'd like, if the try doesn't work (so the ":" is not in the line of the file (and `account[1]` doesn't exist)), to add the ":" after the ".com" of each email on the file. Is that possible?

The output of the third and fourth accounts should be:

```
email3@email.com:test3
email4@email.com:test4
```

Comment: What if an email address does not end with "com"?

Comment: some mistake of who made this list of accounts

Comment: What would be test1?

Comment: the password of the account

Comment: But not in plain text I guess?

Comment: I noticed you've already asked a question with almost the same code, but a different problem, gathered answers (one of which was mine) and then deleted the question. Now the code of this post contains my solution to the question I mentioned earlier. Asking a question and deleting it after receiving answers is _not_ how the Stack Exchange network (and Stack Overflow in particular) works.

Comment: `.comtest4` is a perfectly valid top level domain name. Or at least, it *could* be.

Comment: @ForceBru wow, the nerve. Have you thought about raising a flag for this?

Comment: @Jim, to be honest, I didn't manage to find the right type of flag and decided to post a comment instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `correct_accounts` function to your code.

```
def correct_accounts(accounts):
    corr = []
    for x in accounts:
        if ':' not in x:
            # Assuming all mail addresses end with .com
            pos = x.find ('.com') + 4
            corr.append(x [:pos] + ':' + x [pos:])
        else:
            corr.append(x)
    return corr
```

and call:

```
y = [x.strip().split(":") for x in correct_accounts(accounts)]
```

Comment: your method works fine, but if there is an email like "e.mail@email.com:test", it converts to: "e.m:ail@email.com".. how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it and it didn't. `In [8]: correct_accounts(['e.mail@email.com:test'])
Out[8]: 
['e.mail@email.com:test']` It skips all strings that contain `:`, so it just returns them as from the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for splitting your lines:

```
In [37]: s1 = 'email2@email.com:test2'
In [38]: s2 = 'email3@email.comtest3'

In [42]: regex = re.compile(r'(.+\.com):?(.*)')

In [43]: regex.search(s1).groups()
Out[43]: ('email2@email.com', 'test2')

In [44]: regex.search(s2).groups()
Out[44]: ('email3@email.com', 'test3')
```

And in your code:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(.+\.com):?(.*)')

with open("accounts.txt") as f:
    for ind, line in enumerate(f):
        try:
            part1, part2 = regex.search(line.strip()).groups()
        except:
            pass
        else:
            print ("Trying with: {}:{} @{}".format(part1, part2, ind))
```